# JS changing values for multiple class labels

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class with numerous labels, what I would like to do is change all of the labels in the class with javascript. I am having trouble figuring out how to access the index of the individual labels to change each one dynamically. I will assume it is possible, I just want to change all of the values individually in the class 'row labels'. So change 0,1,5,20,50 to something like 0,5,50,100,200 in javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="session">
        <h2>Count</h2>
        <div class="row colors"></div>
        <div class="row labels">
          <div class="label">0</div>
          <div class="label">1</div>
          <div class="label">5</div>
          <div class="label">20</div>
          <div class="label">50</div>
          <div class="label">90+</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your expected output logic is not clear.. Can you explain in detail of your reuirement?? On what basis you need to change the value of ```class="label"``` ??

Comment: You mean like this?? https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/VwLqNmQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".row.labels .label");
```

will return the list of all labels that can be iterated much like an ordinary array.